# DB2 row level access control: how to pass a user Id

Tags: database, db2

In our web application we want to use DB2 row level access control to control who can view what.  Each table would contain a column named `userId` which contain the user id.  We want log-in users be able to see only row's `usereId` column with theirs id. I have seen db2 permission examples using DB2 `session_id` or `user`, for example taking DB2 given Banking example :

```
CREATE PERMISSION EXAMPLEBANKING.IN_TELLER_ROW_ACCESS
ON EXAMPLEBANKING.CUSTOMER FOR ROWS WHERE BRANCH in (
  SELECT HOME_BRANCH FROM    EXAMPLEBANKING.INTERNAL_INFO WHERE EMP_ID = SESSION_USER
)
ENFORCED FOR ALL ACCESS
ENABLE;
```

Our table gets updated dynamically hence we don't know what row get added or deleted hence we don't know what are all the user Id in the table.

At any given time, different user would log-on to the web to view information retrieve from the tables, the permission declaration above only take `SESSION_USER` as the input, can I change it to something like Java function parameter where one can pass arbitrary id to the permission?  If not then how do I handle different log-in users at arbitrary time?  Or do I just keep changing `SESSION_USER` dynamically as new user login (using "db2 set" ??)?  If so then is this the best practice for this kind use case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user ID in question is application-provided, not originating from the database, using `SESSION_USER`, which equals to the DB2 authorization ID, would not be appropriate. Instead you might use the `CLIENT_USERID` variable, as [described here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005868.html).

This might become a little tricky if you use connection pooling in your application, as the variable must be set each time after obtaining a connection from the pool and reset before returning it to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Trusted Contexts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0609mohan/index.html), this is exactly why they exist.  The linked article is fairly old (you can use trusted contexts with PHP, ruby, etc. now).